# Does Aptana support ES6?

Tags: javascript, aptana, ecmascript-6

Aptana Studio gives me syntax errors for uses of `function*` and `yield` in JavaScript code.

These are ES6 features. Is it possible to configure Aptana to accept them?

Comment: To whoever voted to close this as "too broad": can you please explain why? It seems very specific to me...

Comment: It is back and I up-voted so you should be safe from deletion now (if it keeps having a non-negative score of course)

Answer (score 3):

No, Aptana does not support ES6 (nor JSX) and there are no plugins available to support it.

Aptana is compatible with all [Eclipse plugins](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/). The plugin "[Enide Studio 2015](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/enide-studio-2015-nodejs-javascript-java-and-web-tools)" is tagged with ES6, which is disingenuous because as far as I can tell the only thing it enables a subset of the `const` keyword. Nothing else.

To install the plugin (which won't help you), visit the plugin page, then drag the "install" button into your Aptana editor.

Comment: Thanks. Do you know of another IDE (preferably, but not necessarily, Eclipse-based) that has ES6 support?

Comment: Webstorm is hands down the best IDE for Javascript editing. There's a 30 day free trial and after it expires you can use it for only 1hour at a time. If you can afford it (or get your company to pay for it), it's worth it.

Comment: I don't doubt that JetBrains' product is top-notch. I was hoping for something free and open-source, though. Given that there are numerous high-quality open-source IDEs for other languages like Java, I'm surprised there isn't one for modern Javascript.

Comment: @HighCommander4 did you ever try Komodo Edit? Or did you end up finding something you like?

Comment: Webstorm is by far the best Javascript editor available, but it costs money. Next best is Visual Studio Code, which is free. Next best is Sublime, but Sublime is just a text editor, Webstorm is a full IDE (a code editor), and VSCode is half way between an IDE and a text editor.

Comment: Sublime Text Editor