# JS Unexpected token error in silverstripe-module yeoman generator

Tags: javascript, node.js, silverstripe, yeoman-generator

I recently used Yeoman to scaffold a new Silverstripe project with the silverstripe-module generator. I have npm 2.15.0, node is 4.4.2, and I also updated lodash before running the generator.

Now inside of my dev env (Aptana studio 3), I cloned a git repo (it's an empty private repo), and ran the generator to scaffold a new project in there. 
Everything works fine. Just a warning about updating graceful-fs. 
However, there are several JS errors that have popped up in the Javascript and node_modules>babel-core folders. They are all "Syntax error: unexpected token " errors. 
E.g. in the javascript folder, there are two files, where even simple keywords like "import" and "class" are being shown as unexpected tokens.

```
import is the unexpected token in Main.js:    
        /**
     * This is the entry point to your front-end application.
     * Browserify will create a dependency graph starting from this file,
     * the result will be bundled, and written to javascript/dist/bundle.js which
     * you can include using Requirements::javascript in your controller.
     */

import ExampleComponent from './example-component';

$('.example-component-wrapper').entwine({
    onadd: function () {
        var component = new ExampleComponent();

        component.doStuff();
    }
});
```

class and export are the unexpected tokens in example-component.js:

```
 /**
 * A component that can do stuff.
 */
class ExampleComponent {

    constructor() {

    }

    doStuff() {
        return true;
    }
}

export default ExampleComponent;
```

There are many, many such errors in the node_modules folder. Any ideas?

Comment: Where are these syntax errors being shown? In your dev environment, Yeoman itself or from something else in Node.js? [`import`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/web/javascript/reference/statements/import) and [`class`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes) are actually valid JS in ECMAScript 6.

Comment: @Turnerj In the Dev environment, Aptana Studio.

Comment: @omrakhur maybe this is a valid answer for you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30901152/does-aptana-support-es6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As commented by @FinBoWa above, the development environment is the problem. It doesn't have support for ES6.

[stackoverflow.com/questions/30901152/does-aptana-support-es6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30901152/does-aptana-support-es6)