# Problem with "Syntax error: unexpected token 'let'

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, aptana, aptana3

I'm using AptanaStudio 3 and I'm getting an error with some of my javascript code:

> Syntax error: unexpected token 'let'.

How do I fix this? Maybe there is some way around using `let`? I don't know. I've just started with Javascript and I'm a bit confused. Maybe this is only an AptanaStudio 3 issue?

```
const para = document.querySelector('p');

para.addEventListener('click', updateName);

function updateName() {
    let name = prompt('Enter a new name');
    para.textContent = 'Player1:' + name;
}
```

This Javascript code adds some dynamic behaviour to my html/css code.

Comment: Looks like your browser doesn't support ES6 "let", try replacing let with var

Comment: which browser are you using?

Comment: Aptana is abandoned. It's very likely that it doesn't support modern JavaScript.

Comment: Aptana is heavily outdated. You should use an up-to-date editor/IDE like [Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/).

Answer (score 2):

In this context, `var` is syntactically identical to `let`, and is much more widely supported, particularly on Microsoft's Internet Explorer. To make your code fully ECMAScript 5 compatible, it would look like this:

```
var para = document.querySelector("p");

para.addEventListener("click", updateName);

function updateName() {
    var name = prompt("Enter a new name");
    para.textContent = "Player1:" + name;
}
```

<sub>(Nothing has changed except replacing ES6 `const` and `let` with ES5 `var`.)</sub>

Comment: If this is an ES6 compatibility issue, wouldn't OP be getting an error with `const` first, and so never see the `let` error?

Answer (score 0):

I've just tested your code and it works correctly! I think the problem is AptanaStudio, you should read: [Does Aptana support ES6?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30901152/does-aptana-support-es6). The thing is, let is an statement that was born with ECMAScript 6, the "new Javascript" ahahah 
Read this article to new more about this update on js power: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_es6.asp

I recommend you look for other IDEs or even start thinking about programming without a real IDE, but with just a text editor like Visual Code or Sublime Text (which I like a lot).

For testing I simply used Visual Studio Code and opened the html file in Google Chrome with the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Document</title>

</head>
<body>
  <p>Player name.</p>
  <script>
    const para = document.querySelector('p');

    para.addEventListener('click', updateName);

    function updateName() {
      let name = prompt('Enter a new name');
      para.textContent = 'Player1:' + name;
    }
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```